# why is my prediction process not working?

Tags: python, android, flutter, machine-learning

I am trying to develop a crop recommendation flutter app. I have my trained model and I was trying to integrate that to my flutter user interface but I am not getting any result on the prediction process:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'recommand_page.dart';

import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

Future<String> loadModel() async {
  return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/model.pkl');
}

Future<String> predictCrop(Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
  final jsonString = jsonEncode(data);
  final process = await Process.run('python', ['predict_crop.py', jsonString]);
  return process.stdout.toString();
}

class GrassPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const GrassPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _GrassPageState createState() => _GrassPageState();
}

class _GrassPageState extends State<GrassPage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  Map<String, dynamic> _formData = {};

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadModel();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 8, 105, 51),
        title: Text(
            'Crop Recommendation ',
            style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255)),
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Enter temprature(00.00°C).',
                    labelText: 'Temperature',
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value!.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter temperature(00.00°C).';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    _formData['Temperature'] = double.parse(value!);
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: 'Enter Humidity(00.00).',
                              labelText: 'Humidity',
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value!.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter humidity(00.00).';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    _formData['Humidity'] = double.parse(value!);
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: 'Enter Rainfall(000.00)',
                              labelText: 'Rainfall',
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value!.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter rainfall(000.00).';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    _formData['Rainfall'] = double.parse(value!);
                  },
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: _formKey.currentState?.validate() ?? false ? () async {
                        print('Hello');
                      if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                        print('Form is valid');
                        _formKey.currentState!.save();
                        final predictionString =
                            await predictCrop(_formData);
                        final prediction =
                            jsonDecode(predictionString)['prediction'];
                        String cropName = '';
                        if (prediction == 20) {
                        cropName = 'Rice';
                        } else if (prediction == 11) {
                        cropName = 'Maize';
                        } else if (prediction == 8) {
                        cropName = 'Jute';
                        } else if (prediction == 6) {
                        cropName = 'Cotton';
                        } else if (prediction == 4) {
                        cropName = 'Coconut';
                        } else if (prediction == 17) {
                        cropName = 'Papaya';
                        } else if (prediction == 16) {
                        cropName = 'Orange';
                        } else if (prediction == 0) {
                        cropName = 'Apple';
                        } else if (prediction == 15) {
                        cropName = 'Muskmelon';
                        } else if (prediction == 21) {
                        cropName = 'Watermelon';
                        } else if (prediction == 7) {
                        cropName = 'Grapes';
                        } else if (prediction == 12) {
                        cropName = 'Mango';
                        } else if (prediction == 1) {
                        cropName = 'Banana';
                        } else if (prediction == 19) {
                        cropName = 'Promegranate';
                        } else if (prediction == 10) {
                        cropName = 'Lentil';
                        } else if (prediction == 2) {
                        cropName = 'Blackgram';
                        } else if (prediction == 14) {
                        cropName = 'Mugbean';
                        } else if (prediction == 13) {
                        cropName = 'Mothbeans';
                        } else if (prediction == 18) {
                        cropName = 'Pigeonpeas';
                        } else if (prediction == 9) {
                        cropName = 'Kidneybeans';
                        } else if (prediction == 3) {
                        cropName = 'Chickpea';
                        } else if (prediction == 5) {
                        cropName = 'Coffee';
                        }

                        final snackBar =
                        SnackBar(content: Text('Predicted crop is 
                       $cropName[0]'));
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);

                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => RecommandPage(
                              cropName: cropName[0],
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                    }: null,
                    child: Text('Submit'),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my code. It has no error as well as all the libraries, dependencies and assets as properly set up but I am getting an error nor a result it just stay at as it is. [image]